# How to express it in this situation?

Tags: word-usage

I placed the order on two pizzas and two sauces. but I received two pizzas and one sauce.

In the above situation. Can I say "I didn't get receive one more sauce.", "I received less sauce", "I need one more sauce"
or are there other expressions to clarify my purpose ?

Comment: One sauce is missing/lacking from the order.    Or    I received only one of the two sauces I ordered.

Comment: You can say.  I received incomplete order, I ordered two sauces but got one.

Comment: Boris - **An** incomplete order.